# Configure Live Agent business hours

Tags: liveagent

Is there any way, we can configure the Live agent in salesforce, to work only during business hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavan,

I don't think there is specific business hours setup for Live Agent.

The chat button code you add to your site hooks up to a specific live chat button id which has assigned skills and in turn users with those skills.

The chat button will go online / offline based on users with the matching skills available..

So as long as you configure your users availability it will take care of live agent availability as well.

Note : Individual Chat Agents can [change their status](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=live_agent_change_status.htm&language=en_US) as well.

Comment: thnx Vamsi. yeah you are right. But was curious to know if we can make it work in some way.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not built in, but I took some javascript and made it possible without to much work. The line with liveagont.init you should already have in your page, and if you add the 4 lines above it will work

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var Digital=new Date()
  var hour=Digital.getHours()
  var day=Digital.getDay()
  if ((day > 0 && day < 6) && (hour >= 12 && hour <= 17)) 
    liveagent.init('https://d.la4-c2-was.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', 'xxxxxxxx', '0000000');
</script>
```

Basically it gets the hour and day then checks if its a working day and if that is true it will check if it is between the normal business hours.

Only issue is that it doesn't recheck after the page loads, if someone wants to add an asynchronous solution that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you're prechat page is hosted on a force.com site page, you can use apex to query the out of box business hours and holidays object so that you dont have to maintain hours in hardcoded javascript.